How do you create an automatically rotating image carousel in UWP?
I'm wondering if there is a way to create an automatically rotating image carousel in UWP that will change the background image every few seconds. I've tried using FlipView but I notice there is no way to have it rotate through the images automatically. Is there a way to do this?
This is what I tried, however in this approach I have to click on the arrow to change to the next image:
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BackgroundImages">
        <FlipView>
            <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Image1.png"></Image>
            <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Image2.png"></Image>
        </FlipView>
    </DataTemplate>


It is recommended to use Carousel control, representing a nice and smooth carousel, you can also use FlipView.

create an automatically rotating image carousel in UWP?

We can use DispatcherTimer to modify the current SelectedIndex regularly for Carousel control or FlipView.
//xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
 <Grid>
     <controls:Carousel x:Name="CarouselControl" InvertPositive="True" ItemDepth="300"
                ItemMargin="0" ItemRotationX="0"
                ItemRotationY="0" ItemRotationZ="0"
                TransitionDuration="500" 
                Orientation="Horizontal">
         <controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
             <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
         </controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>

         <controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <Image Width="200"
               Height="200"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Source="{Binding}"
               Stretch="Uniform" />
             </DataTemplate>
         </controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
     </controls:Carousel>
   
 </Grid>


 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
 {
     DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
    
     ObservableCollection<string> imgPath=new ObservableCollection<string>();

     public MainPage()
     {
         this.InitializeComponent();

         imgPath.Add("ms-appx:///Assets/OIP.jpg");
         imgPath.Add("ms-appx:///Assets/OIP.jpg");
         imgPath.Add("ms-appx:///Assets/OIP.jpg");
         imgPath.Add("ms-appx:///Assets/OIP.jpg");
         imgPath.Add("ms-appx:///Assets/OIP.jpg");
         imgPath.Add("ms-appx:///Assets/OIP.jpg");

         CarouselControl.ItemsSource = imgPath;

         DispatcherTimerSetup();
     }

     public void DispatcherTimerSetup()
     {
         dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
         dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
         dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2); 
            
         dispatcherTimer.Start();      
     }

     public int count = 0;
     public void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
     {
         count++;
         if (imgPath.Count > 0)
         {
             CarouselControl.SelectedIndex = count % imgPath.Count;
         }
        
     }
   
 }

